# Closed Testing in Play store when there is already an app published to production as private app

Tags: android, apk, applicationid

I have a question regarding the play store console.

I have a private app that is already in production in the private store with its unique ID, say "com.android.Y". Now I want to upload a new APK with a different Application ID "com.android.X" in the closed testing track inside the same application that is in the production. Is it possible to do so?

Also, is it possible to delete this closed testing track with its APK and Application ID permanently when it is released to users. or if it stays in the closed testing track of the production application , is it possible to upload that APK "com.android.X" as a new application in production while that App with "com.android.X" still exist in the track

I thought under the application in production I only can have different tracks but with the same Application ID

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.